# How can I change my keyboard layout in Centos6.6, xfce4.8

Tags: centos, keyboard, xfce, keyboard-layout

I have a [Cherry G80-3000LSCGB-2 uk-105](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1736979.pdf) keyboard. I use a `Centos6.6` dsitribution that runs a `xfce4.8` desktop.
I access it through `Windows VNC` (don't think it matters but you never know)

On windows I have no problem getting the uk english keyboard
[image]

But there is no way on linux.
Typically when I press [`] (backtick) nothing happen.

I tried to use `Settings > Keyboard > Layout` but none of the uk keyboard are not giving me the proper behaviour.

[image]

How can I get the proper layout ?
Also I have no root, so if possible a no-root solution (though I guess I can ask to an admin)

Answer (score 4):

You may use the `loadkeys` command,  For example

```
loadkeys us
```

would activate US English keyboard. Check [[ this ]](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-kybd.html).

This might not be an easy process, to know where your `.map` files are located, you could do below

```
sudo find / -type f -iname "*.map"
```

from the results try,

```
sudo loadkeys /path/from/find/filename.map
```

Comment: I get Loading /lib/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/uk.map.gz
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
when I do it

Comment: I think I made it work, I am fairly sure this has to do with windows extended keyboard that was selected when vnc was connection to the linux box